# Scala, create a bidimensional array to manages users

Tags: scala

i have a problem. I'm having trouble creating a method that takes a user's name as input and manages how many times a user is named. Basically I have this map as data:

```
private var players: Seq[GamePlayer] = _
```

and game player:

```
case class GamePlayer(override val id: String, username: String, override val actorRef: ActorRef) extends Player
```

from this map I have to create a method that, taken as input a name of a user, creates a two-dimensional array Array [String] [Int] in which a name is associated with the number of times that user is named. Any ideas about it?
I managed to do this but I just don't know how to create and manage a two-dimensional array at scale.
sorry but I'm new to scala and I'm only starting to understand things now ^^"
Thanks

```
private def manageVote(username: String): Unit = {
    //var matrixOfVotes = Array.ofDim[String][Int](this.numberOfPlayers,2)
    var numberOfVotes = this.numberOfPlayers
    var votes = new Array[Int](this.numberOfPlayers)
    isEmpty(username) match {
      case true => numberOfVotes=numberOfVotes-1
      case false => numberOfVotes=numberOfVotes-1
        votes.add(players.indexOf(username))
    }
}
```

and isEmpty:

```
private def isEmpty(x: String) = Option(x).forall(_.isEmpty)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no such a thing in Java/Scala Array's as you tried to describe `Array [String] [Int]` - two dimensional array as name stands is an array of arrays, like: `Array[Array[Int]]`.

What you want is `Map[String, Int]`. If you would like to, how many times `Player` with specific name appears in `Seq[GamePlayer]` you can use just `groupBy` operation, like:

```
players.groupBy(_.username).map {
  case(username, players) => username -> players.size
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! But now how can i save username off all users in an Array[Array[String]] with length of players.size?

Comment: @FounderOnepiecepower Could you please describe what would you like to keep in this array?

Comment: I would like an array with username and number of times that username was returned as method input

Comment: @FounderOnepiecepower as I said before, you are looking for map and not array. You can think of two intentional array as basically matrix or table, and it's not cover case of relation between username of something else.